# How to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin{(n\theta_0)}|}{n}$ diverges for given $\theta_0\in (0,\pi)$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

How to prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{|\sin{(n\theta_0)}|}{n}$ diverges for given $\theta_0\in (0,\pi)$?   I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**

$$
\sum_n \frac{|\sin n\theta_0|}{n} \geq \sum_n \frac{ \sin^2 n\theta_0 }{n}=\sum_n \frac{ 1-\cos 2n\theta_0 }{2n}$$

Comment: I'm struggling for some time trying to show that $\sum \frac{\cos(2n\theta_0)}{n}$ converges. I know that by Dirichlelt's test it suffices to show that $s_n=\sum_n \cos(2n\theta_0)$ is bounded, but I don't know how to deal with this as well.

Comment: Use geometric series partial sum on $\sum_n e^{2in\theta_0}$