# $\sum\limits_{n=1}^∞ \frac{|\sin(n\theta)|}{n}$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, divergent-series

> Let $\theta$ be any fixed constant in $(0,\pi/2)$. Then the seires $$\sum_{n=1}^∞ \frac{|\sin(n\theta)|}{n}$$ diverges.

I don't have any idea how to prove it.
Maybe equidistribution theorem is related?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here's how: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Can you find a subsequence for a given constant that is always within $\epsilon$ of a given value for each term?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/938894/how-to-prove-that-sum-n-1-infty-frac-sinn-theta-0n-diverges-fo/938960#938960

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I don't know how to use that hint.

Comment: @i707107 Coud you help me how to use that hint?

Comment: Consider the partial sum $\sum_{n\leq N} \frac{ 1-\cos 2n\theta_0 }{2n}$, The series with $\cos$ converges, but the series with $1/(2n)$ diverges.

Comment: Use Dirichlet's test to show that$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\cos(2n\theta)}{2n}<\infty,\quad\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$$And then compare to the harmonic series.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$|\sin (nt)| \ge \sin^2 (nt) = \frac{1-\cos (2nt)}{2}.$$

If we show

$$\tag 1 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left( \frac{1}{2n}- \frac{\cos (2nt)}{2n}\right)$$

diverges, we'll be done. Now $(1)$ is the sum of two series, the first of which diverges as you know, the second of which converges by Dirichlet's test. Hence $(1)$ diverges, which implies the original series diverges.

Comment: Mmm, I'm not sure how I feel about [answering questions like this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27031/answers-to-obvious-duplicates).

Comment: Just to add on this, $\sum \cos (2nt)$ is bounded for any choice of $t \ne \pi$

Comment: @RabMakh Take $t=2\pi$ :P

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This is one of the reasons I fail my exams, I always assume the examiner understands whats in my mind :') I should be more careful when writing arguments.

Comment: :-) And I suppose that's what I'm here for, to remind you of those mistakes I guess @RabMakh

Comment: @zhw.  (+1) ... That's the way I would show divergence here.

Comment: I'm struggling for some time trying to show that $\sum\cos(2nθ_0)/n$ converges. I know that by Dirichlelt's test it suffices to show that $s_n=\sum_n\cos(2nθ_0)$ is bounded, but I don't know how to deal with this as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint** The standard arguments on the density of $n \frac{\theta}{2 \pi}$ modulo 1 can be changed to show that for each $\theta \in (0 , \frac{\pi}{2})$ there exists some $M$ so that among any $M$ consecutive numbers $n+1, n+2,.., n+M$ you can find some $m$ so that 
$$|\sin(m \theta)| \geq \frac{1}{2}$$

Conclude from here that your series is larger than 
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2} \frac{1}{kM}$$