# prove that $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n}$ is divergent

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, trigonometric-series

I tried much to show that the following series is divergent for $x \in (0,\pi)$

$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}  \frac{|\sin(nx)|}{n}$

My opinion was to use the comparison test with series $\frac{1}{n}$ but I could not achieve something good.

Thank for your time.

Comment: Are you allowed to use [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test)?

Comment: yes, maybe. There is no restrictions but simple methods are better.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/938894/42969

Comment: @schneiderlog Using condensation test, your series converges if and only if $\sum |\sin(2^nx)|$ converges.

Answer (score -1):

Proof using Dirichlet's test:
Firstly I'll introduce the test:

Given a sequence $\{a_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ and a sequence $\{b_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ satisfying:

- $\{a_n\}_{1}^{\infty}$ is monotonic
- $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = 0$
- $
   \left|
    \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n
   \right| \leq M
  $
  for every positive integer $N$

The series $
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cdot b_n
$ converges.

Let us define $
  a_n = \frac{1}{n}
$ and
$
  b_n = \left|
  sin(n\cdot x)
 \right|
$.

We know that $a_n$ is monotonic and converges to 0.

All we have left to prove is that
$
 \left|
  \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n
 \right| =
\left|
  \sum_{n=1}^{N}
   \left|
    sin(n\cdot x)
   \right|
 \right| =
  \sum_{n=1}^{N}
   \left|
    sin(n\cdot x)
   \right|
\leq M
$ for every positive integer $N$

We know that $\left| sin(n \cdot x)\right| \leq 1$ and so
$\sum_{n=1}^{N}
   \left|
    sin(n\cdot x)
   \right| \leq
\sum_{n=1}^{N}
    1 = N
$

And so for every positive integer $N$:

$
 \left|
  \sum_{n=1}^{N} b_n
 \right| \leq N
$

According to Dirichlet's test, we get that:

$
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cdot b_n =
  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{
\left|
    sin(n\cdot x)
   \right|
}{n}
$ converges.

$$\blacksquare$$

Comment: The answer is wrong: take $x=\pi/2.$